# How to return JSON Result in MVC2 at Post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ajax post method to post the form like :-

> $(function () {
>
> ```
>         $('#BtnName').submit(function () {
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: 'Home/Index',
>                 type: "POST",
>                 data: $(this).serialize(),
>                 dataType: "json",
>                 async:false,
>                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>                 success: function (data) { var message = data.Result; $("#Result").html(message); },
>                
>
>             });
>             return false;
>         });
>     });
> ```

At the action controller i m returning

> return Json(new { Result = "Success" },
> JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

i m not able to get the Result in the div ; instead of this its returning the whole render page as complete file. Please tell me what should i do do to show the result on the page and also want to on the same page without clearing the form.

Comment: show all of the controller code.

Comment: i m just inesterting values in the database and at the end of controller i m using return Json(new { Result = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: you are calling home/index in your ajax method. are you sure it is the same method that is returning json?

Comment: yes,that method is returning JsonResult as  public JsonResult Index(FormCollection frm)

Comment: why would you need `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` if your `POST`'ing to your action method? You don't need that. What does Fiddler show coming back from the HTTP POST?

Comment: URL is appearing blank in Fiddler only displaying / I have also removed JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet but the result is same and I m getting one file containing { Result = "Success" }. Please tell me what should i do to resolve it.

Comment: What am I missing? From the above it seems your action is returning what you want it to? Alert your message variable. You definitely have a div with an id attribute set as "Result"

Comment: I have tried differnt option and nothing is working fr me right now

Comment: What are you expecting to get back from your action besides {Result = "Success"}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, the code bits contained in your question are absolutely insufficient to draw any conclusions. So let's do a full example.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // TODO : process the model ...

        return Json(new { Result = "Success" });
    }
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })) { %>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo) %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
<% } %>
```

External javascript to unobtrusively AJAXify the form:

```
$(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var message = data.Result; 
                $('#Result').html(message);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Things to notice:

- I am attaching the `.submit` event to the if of the form (`#myForm`), whereas in your example you are using `#BtnName` which looks a strangely suspicious name for a form. Unfortunately you haven't shown your markup so we don't know what it actually represents
- I am no longer hardcoding the url of the form (`Home/Index`) but relying on the one generated by the `Html.BeginForm`. There are two benefits of this: 1. youcan now put your javascript into a separate file => you are no longer mixing markup and script and your HTML pages now become smaller and faster to load (the external static javascript files are cached) and 2. when you deploy your application on some other server or you decide to change your routes it will still work without any modification on your js.
- I am no longer using `contentType: 'application/json'` because when you use `$(this).serialize()` this doesn't serialize the form into JSON. It serializes it into a  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` style. So you are basically introducing a contradiction: 
  you are telling the server that you will send a JSON request but in practice you don't.
- I have removed the `async: false` attribute as this does a synchronous request and freezes the browser during its execution. It is no longer AJAX. So unless you want this, don't use it.
- I have removed the `dataType: 'json'` parameter as jQuery is intelligent enough to deduce this from the actual response `Content-Type` header and automatically parse the returned JSON and pass it to the success callback as a javascript object that you could directly use.

Comment: does this apply to .post() aswell? and how would somebody to handle errors, like all results that get back is success (at least what i have experienced sometimes), because in the controller i have to make a return right, lets say the model is not valid, what do i return then?

Comment: @Dejan.S, there are many ways and no single answer. All will depend on your exact scenario and what you are trying to achieve. One way would be to put this form into a partial and have the controller action return this partial in case of validation error (so that fields that have errors could be highlighted in red) and in case of success return JSON. Then in the AJAX success callback you could check whether the returned result is a JSON object and if not inject the new partial into the DOM so that errors could be shown. There are other more RESTful ways using response HTTP status codes.

Comment: i got a scenario but i dont got the code right here, ill make a new question and maybe you will answer it :), but i got what you mean with the partial, that was one of my thoughts. thanks for the reply

Comment: This is Showing an error message
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details: Error parsing near '{"Result":"Success"}'.