# Call C# method from JavaScript and return a string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a web page that displays the columns from a table in SQL Server. Several of the columns must be have select lists and the value of several columns must change depending on the selected item. 
As an example, I have a table called `Accounts` that has an `AccountNumber` and `AccountName` column. I want the AccountName cell on the web page to change depending on the AccountNumber selection from the select list. I've tried using JavaScript and jQuery to pass the `AccountNumber` to a C# method that gets the `AccountName`, but when I make a selection and debug I get an error saying that the parameter the method received can't be null.

**JavaScript**

```
function getAccountNumber(x) {
        var selectedAccountNumber = document.getElementById(x.id).value;
        var isNumber = isNaN(selectedAccountNumber);
        if (!isNumber) {
            var accountNumber = parseInt(selectedAccountNumber, 10);
            var accountName = $.post('@Url.Action("GetAccountName", "Statements")', accountNumber);
            alert(accountName);
        }
    }
```

**C#**

```
public string GetAccountName(int ID)
{
    var item = db.Accounts.Where(acc => acc.AccountNumber == ID).Select(acc => acc.AccountName).Single();
    return item;
}
```

I don't know why it's not passing the parameter properly.

Comment: Please have a look detail at official site , how to use $.post
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: The problem is: you can not! call straight code.... you need to call and endpoint. aka something which exposes the code c# this is normally done with Web project (MVC). you need to first fix how you are exposing your c# then toy with the java-script.

Comment: Are you missing the _Post_ decorator above the action?

Comment: @schlonzo yes. I thought it would interfer with the method since it's prefix is "GET".

Comment: @IsaacOpperman So why are you using $.post then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return JSON Result in MVC2 at Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715471/how-to-return-json-result-in-mvc2-at-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetAccountName(int ID)
{
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var item = db.Accounts.Where(acc => acc.AccountNumber == ID).Select(acc => acc.AccountName).Single();
  return js.Serialize(item.ToString());

}

var accountNumber = parseInt(selectedAccountNumber, 10);
var targetUrl= "@Url.Action("GetAccountName", "Statements")"+ "?ID=" + accountNumber;
$.post(targetUrl, function (data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: You don't need to serialise the string to JSON manually, and you really shouldn't be recommending `JavaScriptSerializer` in 2019!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem with this code is the object that you are passing as a parameter, it has to be a list type:

```
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetAccountName", "Statements")', {ID: accountNumber }, function(htmlexterno){
           $("#cargaexterna").html(htmlexterno);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: you can not! call straight code.... you need to call an endpoint. aka something which exposes the code c# this is normally done with Web project (MVC). you need to first fix how you are exposing your c# then toy with the java-script.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SomeNameController : ControllerBase
{
    public SomeNameController()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Get((int id)
    {
        return "cat";
    }
}
```

**Update**

JS

```
var accountNumber = parseInt(selectedAccountNumber, 10);
var data { id : accountNumber };
var url = '@Url.Action("GetAccountName", "Statements")';
$.post(url, data);
```

Comment: I am using MVC. 
Should I rather try and use a method that returns a `JsonResult`?

Comment: it was not clear from your snip that you are infact using mvc maybe include the controller level as well, so the routing can be verified also include your routing and mark up on the controller/action @IsaacOpperman

Comment: if the second param on the post JS is the data object then you need to specify the value and then the type... ill give an example in my update

Comment: I changed it to { ID = accountNumber } and it still doesn't work.

Comment: like i said include the error and update the code so that more can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to keep it as simple as possible i.e. used regular JQuery function and MVC controller.

**Server side**

```
 public ActionResult GetAccountName(string accountNumber)
 {
    return Content("Account name of " + accountNumber);
 }
```

**Client Side (Script)**

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".accountnumbers").change(function () {
            var accountNumber = $(this).val();
            var labelToUpdate = $("#" + $(this).data("label"));

            console.log(labelToUpdate);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAccountName", "Home")',
                data: { "accountNumber": accountNumber},
                success: function (data) {

                    labelToUpdate.html(data);
                }
            })

        })
    });
</script>
```

For simplicity I've used static IDs of control, you can make it dynamic if you have more than one account number field.

**Client Side HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Account Number
    </td>
    <td>
        Account Name
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtAccountNumber_1" class="accountnumbers" data-label="lblAccountName_1" />
    </td>
    <td><label id="lblAccountName_1"></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```